# C# cast audio form resources

Tags: c#, audio, casting

i need some help regarding the following:

```
HomeArrayPicBox[i, j].Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Scan" + i);

SoundPlayer fire = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.fire);
```

for the picbox i can load an image from resources using cast (Image).

i was wondering how to do this for audio i.e. some sort of (Audio)?

is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Just use streams:

```
System.IO.Stream stream = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetStream("resource_name");
System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(stream);
```